# Gem "google-api-client" を Rails Controller 内から利用したいが `cannot load such file -- google/apis/sheets_v4` となる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, rake

### 問題点

Rails Controller から　require すると失敗する.

```
cannot load such file -- google/apis/sheets_v4
```

## 利用している Gem

`gem "google-api-client"`

```
google-api-client (0.53.0)
  google-apis-core (~> 0.1)
  google-apis-generator (~> 0.1)
```

### 備考1. Rakeタスクからだと成功する（Success require from rake tasks）

以下のような `lib/tasks/xxxx.rake` 上においては正常にロードができ、Google API 認証も成功します。

```
# Success require's
require "google/apis/sheets_v4"

namespace :retrieve_google_spreadsheed do

  desc "hogehoge"
  task hogehoge_tasks: :environment do

    @service = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::SheetsService.new
...
```

### 備考2. 他のバージョンも試したが同じ（Same problem for other versions)

Github Issue 等の情報を参考に非互換バージョンである、0.7 等も試しましたが、同じ結果に。
そもそも Rails Controller や Concerns 内から利用するようなソフトでない事は承知ですが、詳細な理由を知りたいと考えております。

以上、宜しくお願いします。